# Any value to a "deleted because" comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, deleted-posts

A few minutes ago, I asked a stupid question on Meta - or rather made a mistaken bug report. A few seconds later, I realised it was stupid and deleted it.

So far so good - but I couldn't help noticing that 2 people had already read it, and I wanted to apologise. But editing the question or adding a comment would mean wasting even more people's time, leaving a stupid question visible when it could have been deleted already.

So, I thought, perhaps it would make sense to have an optional deletion comment. Delete the item immediately, but request a comment, and (if given) push that out to anyone reading the item, similar to the "new answers" thing that's displayed when you're writing an answer.

That way, I could have said "I'm an idiot, sorry for wasting your time" when I deleted my stupid question, and perhaps have wasted a bit less of at least two peoples time.

Of course I could have avoided wasting peoples time entirely by not being stupid - but that's a bit challenging at times.

Comment: I don't think that anyone was terribly inconvenienced by reading a single question, so you should probably be worrying far less about it than you seem to be.

Comment: Not worrying - just discussing an idea. If I was that worried, it'd be a feature request with a "how *dare* you prevent a British person from appologising!" tone.

Comment: Maybe this should be a feature request to allow a single comment after deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing, you can still add a short comment to users using the `@username` saying "`Sorry for wasting your time, My bad, deleting my question.`"

Once you add comment you can then delete your question. What this will do is send an alerts in the user's inbox with the message. Atleast those users will know by reading that message in their inbox, but if they click, they will not find the link on website. No problem, the message is anyway conveyed to the users. Also deleting your question will not waste any other user's time too :)

NOTE: All the above hold good only if the answers do not have any upvotes.

Comment: There were no answers/comments yet - I was just looking at the "viewed ? times" thing. I tried leaving a comment after deleting, and it wasn't allowed - I figured every second before deleting was a chance of wasting another persons time.

Comment: @Steve314 - Oh, if it was only views, then there is nothing much you can do dude. Just delete your question its fine. Btw, you can add comment before deleting the question and then delete the question, it is ok but makes no sense in your case anyway. My answer holds good only if users have added answers to your questions. Dont worry abt views. You should worry only if ppl start answering... more worried if they are upvoted. :)